# Silverlight ChartingToolKit is not coming in xaml page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, charts

i wanted to implement charts in my silverlight app.

i have installed SL4 in my VS.

The problem is i m not getting the **chartingToolkit:Chart** control in my xaml page.
Gives error saying  control not found .

Did i forget to add any references?
or did my installation went wrong?
do i have to download any other plugin?

Thanks
Sajad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chartings controls are from the Silverlight toolkit, you need to install it first.;) 
http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: i had already installed that.. ;).otherwise i wont be able to create a silverlight app at all .

Comment: do you have these references? System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit, System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit and System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals, also, define xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" and try using toolkit:Chart

Comment: Adding this to the namespace area worked :) xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"   Thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

i have added the assemblies as mentioned by Xin.

**System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit,**

System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit

System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals

But my problem was actually solved by adding this to namespace area.

**xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"**

and then i could use toolkit:Chart

:)

Comment: did you see my last comment? yes, you can reference like what you showed above, but what's better is have this xmlns:toolkit="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit instead, this way you will have everything provided in the toolkit by doing toolkit:xxx, mine is the better answer...